# c++ type writing effect with special characters

Tags: c++

I've been working on a console project which will print characters into the console one by one giving the type writing effec.

I've looked at several posts and so far have come up with this:

```
void printchar(char cal, int speed){
    char str[]={cal};
    int len = strlen(str);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){cout<<myStory[x]; Sleep(speed);}
}

void printmsg(char myStory[], int speed){
    for (unsigned int x=0; x<strlen(myStory); x++){cout << myStory[x]; Sleep(speed);}
}

int main()
{
    char cal[] = {178,177};
    printchar(cal,25);
    cout<<endl;
    printmsg("test",25);
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can print several unicode characters if I do

```
void printchar(char cal, int speed){
    char str[]={112,78,178,103,178,112};
    int len = strlen(str);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){cout<<myStory[x]; Sleep(speed);}
}
```

but I get an additional 7 characters or so after the unicode ones are printed.

I'm wondering how to print the unicode characters without the additional ones and also being able to change the cal variable so I can define which characters I want to print outside the function.

What would be ideal is if I could print unicode characters and a string from the same function but at different times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors, here's three of them:

- With `char str[]={cal};` followed by the `strlen(str)` call, you have *undefined behavior*. The `strlen` function looks for the string terminator character `'\0'`, which you have not added to the array.
- With

  ```
  char cal[] = {178,177};
  printchar(cal,25);
  ```

  you call a function taking a single `char` with an array of `char`.
- In the `printchar` function you reference the undeclared `myStory` variable.

There are probably other problems as well.

Enable warnings when compiling (if you're using GCC or Clang add at least the `-Wall` option), then ***read*** all warning and error messages. Look at the lines they reference. Try to understand what the errors and warning means. Fix the causes of the errors and warnings. And when fixing warnings, don't just try to hide them by simple type-casting and such, really fix them. If you don't understand why you get the errors and warnings you get, you will never go far as a programmer.

Comment: ok i think ive almost got it sorted

    void printchar(char cal, int speed){
    char str[]={cal};
    int len = strlen(str);
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str) ;i++){cout<<str[i]; Sleep(speed);}
    }

but i have no idea how or where to implement the terminator function ?

Comment: @NanoedStux All strings in C is one character longer than its "length", and that extra character is the terminator character `'\0'`. So for a one-character string you would have e.g. `char str[] = { cal, '\0' };`

Comment: awesome worked perfectly, do you have any suggestions as to how i could put multiple unicode values into the function?